# R plotting mean and standard deviation of simple dataframe without data manipulation

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a simple dataframe `data`

```
  V1 V2 V3 V4 V5
1  3  3  3  5  6
2  3  4  6 10 12
3  5  6  8 10 11
4  4  5  7  9 11
5  2  3  5  8  9
```

This data represents performance during the game for each round. For example in the game 4, a person scored 7 in the third iteration.

And I am trying to create a plot like this (a plot is taken from [here](http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/Plotting_means_and_error_bars_%28ggplot2%29/)):

[image]

where on the x axis will rounds and on the y axis the average performance with standard deviation as bars. The average performance is for the first round will be average in the column V1 (3.4), for the second round - 4.2. Standard deviation is also calculated based on V column.

Thanks to BeasterField, I am converting my data in the following way:

```
df$n <- rownames(df)
df <- melt(df, id.vars="n", value.name="perf", variable.name="iter" )
dfc <- ddply(df, .(iter), summarise, se = sd( perf )/sqrt(length(perf)), perf = mean(perf))
```

which gives me the following result:

```
  iter        se perf
1   V1 0.5099020  3.4
2   V2 0.5830952  4.2
3   V3 0.8602325  5.8
4   V4 0.9273618  8.4
5   V5 1.0677078  9.8
```

But later, when I am trying to use ggplot

```
ggplot(dfc, aes(x=iter, y=perf))+geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=perf-se, ymax=perf+se), width=.1)+geom_line()+geom_point()
```

I receive : `geom_path: Each group consist of only one observation. Do you need to adjust the group aesthetic?`
The plot is build without connected lines: [image]

Also I want my Y axis to have a maximum value of 20.

Comment: Why can't you manipulate the data frame first? ggplot2 is sort of built around the idea that you reshape your data first and then plot it.

Comment: What do you mean by "without manipulation" and what's the motivation behind the idea?

Comment: The problem with your plot is, that the iter is a categorial variable. If you want to add a `geom_line` to this you need a (pseudo-) group. you can easily fix that with adding `group =1` to the `aes()`. But this is a completely different question than your original one and should be discussed separately as this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can melt a `data.frame` from wide to long format using `reshape2::melt`:

```
library( reshape2 )
mdf$n <- rownames(mdf)
mdf <- melt( mdf, id.vars="n", value.name="perf", variable.name="iter" )
mdf

   n iter perf
1  1   R1    4
2  2   R1    2
3  3   R1    1
4  1   R2    5
5  2   R2    3
6  3   R2    1
...
```

Concerning your actual question

> I am trying to achieve is without manipulation with the dataframe, but without any luck.

you should know, that `ggplot` is designed to work on data.frames in long format. So the procedure to first melt and then plot, is absolutely usual. Sometimes there is also a split-apply-combine-step between the two, as you have indicated with `summarySE`. Without knowing this function, I guess it does something similar like

```
library( plyr)
mdf <- ddply( mdf, .(n), summarise, se = sd( perf )/sqrt(length(perf)), perf = mean(perf)) 
mdf
  n        se perf
1 1 1.0198039  6.8
2 2 0.2000000  2.8
3 3 0.7483315  2.4
```

Using the plot command you showed you'll get
[image]

Comment: Hm, what does `summarySE` do exactly, or how does the result of it look like? I'm asking because if you group based on `iter`, what is the aggregation function for `n`? For plotting I reused, as I wrote, exactly the plot command you showed in your original post.

Comment: SummarySE is taken from http://www.cookbook-r.com/Manipulating_data/Summarizing_data/ and there is an example with its result.

Comment: Ok fine. As you can see from the linked code, `summarySE` does almost do the same as I showed. And while you specify `groupvars = "n"` this is exactly the same as where I specify in the `ddply` command `.(n)`. Probably you should rephrase your question and explain better what you want to have drawn: x-axis, y-axis, groups?